# 301 redirect a folder but exclude child folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a directory "mysite.com/blog" to a new site. However, I do NOT want to redirect a child folder "mysite.com/blog/wp-admin".

Here is my htaccess code which effectively redirects the entire /blog folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog(.*) http://www.newsite.com/newblog [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

I have tried the following to exclude /wp-admin, but that didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/wp-admin(.*)
RewriteRule ^blog(.*) http://www.newsite.com/newblog [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

UPDATE:

I tried removing the (.*) from both lines, as directed, and its still redirecting to the new site. BUT, the URL is different. Here's the URL once it redirects:

http://www.newsite.com/newblog/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Foldsite.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F

Can you tell from this URL what's going wrong? I'm not good at regex, but it looks like it's a formatting issue.

Comment: You sure you've cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: Hmmm... I do not see a problem, although I would remove the `(.*)` at the end of both regex since you do not use the resulting parsed part anywhere (maybe you're missing `\1` at the end of the new URI though... `http://www.newsite.com/newblog\1`.)

Comment: @JonLin -- yes, I've cleared my cache a few times. The /blog/wp-admin directory (and everything in /blog) is still redirecting to the new site. I'm stumped.

Comment: @AlexisWilke I tried it with and without the (.*) to no effect. The /blog/wp-admin directory still redirects to the new site. I also added the \1 to the end, but that just added a "1" to the end of the URL -- what was the desired effect there?

Comment: Sorry! I mean `$1` and not `\1`. The idea is the path gathered by the `(.*)` is put in the first parameter that you can then put in the redirect URL. That's really only if you still have the same URLs on the destination.

Comment: One silly questions: Did you restart your Apache2 server after your changes? It should not matter, because you are using a `.htaccess` file, but at times it's not a bad idea to do a full restart of the server.

Comment: Thanks @AlexisWilke. It's cheap shared hosting, so I'm not able to restart Apache. I did, however, notice that you said to remove the (.*) from BOTH regex, and I only removed it from the first one. I just removed it from both lines, and while it is still redirecting, the URL is different. (edited - it won't put the URL in the comment. I'll add it to my original question.)

Comment: Where htaccess is located? If it is in /blog/ then the pattern must not include 'blog' as it truncated. `RewriteRule . http://www.newsite.com/newblog [L,R=301]`

Comment: @Deadooshka, the .htaccess is in the root. I am redirecting several folders individually from the root.

Comment: you really do not need patterns like `(.*)` there. `!^/blog/wp\-admin` `^blog`. Also check the .htaccess in the /blog/ as it may rewrite previous rules and return back with new url.

Comment: Ah ha. The issue was that I needed to also add a redirect condition for blog/wp-login.php. blog/wp-admin redirects to blog/wp-login.php, and because I didn't have a redirect for that, it sent me on to the new site. Thanks to both of you for getting me there.